# Alter a table add unique key in my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, unique-key

I wrote code like

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Questions] 
ADD UNIQUE (Question);
```

But it shows error like

> Column 'Question' in table 'Questions' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Please help me..

Comment: Please add the DDL statement for your Questions table to your question (no pun intended :-) ).

Comment: the problem is column definition I have given NVARCHAR(MAX) SO it is not altering the table .I solved this thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Questions] ADD constraint q_pk UNIQUE (Question);
```

[See here for documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx)

Comment: I got the solution for my question . column does not contain like nvarchar(MAX). so that it gives error now rectified. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Questions] 
ADD UNIQUE (Question);
Column 'Question' in table 'Questions' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

```
In Question-column of table Questions should not be 'nvarchar(MAX)' but i have 
given before table schema question as nvarchar(max) so it gives such error
```

> Questions' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an
>   index.

I have changed to varchar(255). Its working fine. Thanks.